# How do I find a substring in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get EmailIds input like 'companyby_1234@gmail.com', 'companyby_1256@gmail.com' and want to find the email-ids which have text 'companyby' and filter them, but i don't know where it is in the string.

I want to do this check c# code.

Comment: `string.Contains`, `string.IndexOf`

Comment: Did you even try to search ? *Please do the needful* : Put in some effort before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains is too slow for large numbers of data, plus it matches the domain and the in-the-middle occurences as well.

So use StartsWith

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = //Whatever
foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    //string email = dr("email");
    string email = "companyby_1234@gmail.com";

    if (email != null && email.StartsWith("companyby", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        // do whatever here
    }
}
```

With Linq:

```
var filteredList = IEnumerable<Emails>.Where(email =>  email != null ? email.StartsWith("companyby", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) : false)
```

For Linq, you need to have .NET Framework > 3.0 and you need to add

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
```

Because in there are extension methods.

Comment: To be fair, the OP said "I don't know where it is in the string".

Comment: You are right, wish i could write only Point to :)

Comment: @J. Steen: You're right, I overread that. Note that I missed the @ after companyby for my case...

Answer (score 1):

use a lambda expression

```
var filteredList = IEnumerable<Emails>.Where(email => email.Contains(companyby))
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're using the `.Contains` method, albeit _in_ a lambda expression, in a Linq method chain. =)

Comment: by looking at the question, i think giving a detailed answer would probably throw him further into the dark.

Comment: Point. < I wish I could write a comment this short.